# Don't replace new line with space

Tags: spacing, line-breaking

Is there a way to prevent TeX from replacing new lines with spaces?

This

```
example
text

second
    example
        text
```

results in this

[image]

but what I want this

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Insert `%` at the end of line.

Comment: Wow, that was easy. Thank you very much. If you write this as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That space is called trailing space. But even if you remove blank spaces at the end of line, TeX will insert one when read the line below. So, to remove it, insert `%` at the end, exactly after the last char.

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\begin{verbatim}
example
text

second
    example
        text
\end{verbatim}
example
text

second
    example
        text
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\begin{verbatim}
example%
text

second%
    example%
        text
\end{verbatim}
example%
text

second%
    example%
        text
\end{minipage}

\vskip 1cm 
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\begin{verbatim}
example
text
%
second
    example
        text
\end{verbatim}
example
text
%
second
    example
        text
\end{minipage}%

\end{document}
```